# What is the relation between Intel Intrinsics and x86 Built-in Functions

Tags: gcc, x86, intrinsics

[Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) lists intrinsics for the Intel MMX technology, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, and SSSE3 instructions for Intel C/C++ compiler. [x86 Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions) lists intrinsics for GCC. What is the relation between these two lists?

My guess is that [x86 Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions) is a implementation of [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/). For example, [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) has `__m64 _mm_add_pi16 (__m64 a, __m64 b)` which is implemented as `v4hi __builtin_ia32_paddw (v4hi, v4hi)` in [x86 Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions). So it seems that [x86 Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions) pick some [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)'s intrinsics and does some wrapping such as renaming. But [x86 Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions) does not implement all intrinsics in [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/). For example, `__m64 _mm_shuffle_pi16 (__m64 a, int imm8)`'s SEE instruction is `pshufw`. But [x86 Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions) does not have a intrinsic for this SSE instruction. So it seems that [x86 Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions) does not implements all intrinsics in [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/). To use such intrinsics, we can include [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)'s header file and use `-msse` to do the compile (I have verified this).

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: gcc's version of `immintrin.h` implements the Intel intrinsics on top of the built-in functions.  Just use the Intel intrinsics in your code, unless you're trying to write vector code that can compile for multiple different SIMD architectures (e.g. ARM NEON as well as x86 SSE / AVX).  IIRC, using GNU C generic vector stuff still doesn't help write code that can compile for different lengths of vectors (e.g. one source compiles to 32B vectors for AVX, 16B vectors for SSE).  Also note that `-msse2` is baseline (for x86-64).  You don't need to specify it.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks for your comment.